# Determine whether or not the modules over $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ presented by the following matrices are free

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

I am trying to solve part (c) the following problem from Artin. I have already solved (a) and (b).

> Determine whether or not the modules over $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ presented by the following matrices are free:
>
> (a) $\begin{bmatrix} x^2+1 & x \\ x^2y+x+y & xy+1     \end{bmatrix}$
>
> (b) $\begin{bmatrix} xy-1 \\ x^2-y^2 \\ y     \end{bmatrix}$
>
> (c) $\begin{bmatrix} x-1 & x \\ y & y+1 \\ x & y \\ x^2 & 2y   \end{bmatrix}$

I have determined that the matrix in (a) reduces to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and hence the module is isomorphic to $R^2/\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} R^2\cong R^2/R^2 \cong \{0\}$, hence not free. (According to my professor's definition, "free" means isomorphic to $R^k$ for some $k\in\{1,2,3,...\}$)

---

Likewise, I have determined that the matrix in (b) reduces to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and hence the module is isomorphic to $R^3/\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}R \cong R^2$, hence free.

---

Now, I have determined that the matrix in (c) reduces to $\begin{bmatrix} 1+2y \\ x+y \\ x^3+x-1 \end{bmatrix}$, but I'm having trouble reducing this matrix further. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a typo? The matrix in (c) and the one you say it reduces to are not of the same type (one is $3\times 2$ and the other $3\times 1$).

Comment: Oops, you were right; there was a typo. I have fixed it now. The matrix in (c) should be $4 \times 2$. Note that this can reduce to a $3 \times 1$, where by "reduce" I mean that the either matrix is a valid presentation matrix.

Comment: That is, we can use the elementary row and column operations, but we can also delete a column of zeroes. Also, if column $j$ is the vector $e_i$, we can delete row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: The trivial module is free with empty basis. It satisfies all other equivalent conditions of being free, of course.

Comment: @Pedro My professor doesn't consider the empty set to be a basis. Consequentially, he considers the trivial vector space to be the only vector space not having a basis. This seems to be just a matter of definition, however. In any case, I would like to reduce the matrix in **(c)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your reduction to 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1+2y \\ x+y \\x^3+x-1\end{bmatrix}$$
is correct (I haven't checked), you may subtract the first line $(1/2)$-times from the second. That brings you to
$$\begin{bmatrix}1+2y \\ x-\frac{1}{2} \\x^3+x-1\end{bmatrix},$$
where $ x-\frac{1}{2},\;\; x^3+x-1 \in \mathbb{C}[x],$ which is a PID. Note that the two polynomials are also coprime since $(1/2)$ is not a root of $x^3+x-1$. Thus, there are some polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ (that are computable, but that's not necessary) such that 
$$(x-\frac{1}{2})f(x)+(x^3+x-1)g(x)=1. \;\;\;\;(*)$$
That is, we have an invertible matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & f(x) & g(x) \\ 0 & -(x^3+x-1) & x-\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$
(note that the determinant is $1$ because of $(*)$), and 
$$A \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1+2y \\ x-\frac{1}{2} \\x^3+x-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+2y \\ 1 \\0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Now, using the $1$ in the middle one easily eliminates the first entry. Hence, the module is free.

Comment: (+1) What an elegant proof! However, I think you have a typo. It seems to me that, in your last equation, you should replace $\begin{bmatrix} 1+2y \\ x+y \\ x^3+x-1 \end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix} 1+2y \\ x-0.5 \\ x^3+x-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you, i corrected the typo.